# Как сделать чтобы в фрагменте не использовался тот же тулбар что и в активити?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-toolbar

У меня одно активити и несколько фрагментов, у всех фрагментах тот же тулбар что и в активвити. Как поменять ?

В фрагменьте :

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_log, menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }
```

в активити :

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(searchQueryListener);

        return true;
}

  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.logout:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, bFrag).commit();
                wallcome.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53502/discussion-on-question-by-fedia--------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, вы хотите изменить меню в тулбаре, тогда можно воспользоваться функцией invalidateOptionsMenu(), которая позволяет обновить вид меню. Сделайте какую-нибудь переменную boolean CHECK = false, значение которой изменяется на true, когда вы нажали на логаут, и тогда функция onCreateOptionsMenu будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ваше_меню, menu);
    MenuItem Item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.какой-то_итем1_в_вашем_меню);
    MenuItem Item2 = menu.findItem(R.id.какой-то_итем2_в_вашем_меню); 
    if (!CHECK){
        //логаут ещё не нажат, вид меню начальный
    }else{
       //на логаут нажали, скрыть нужную кнопку в меню или т.п. 
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Когда нажали на логаут, у вас, например запускается код вызова фрагмента, и после этого кода добавьте вызов функции invalidateOptionsMenu();

Comment: а как потом вернуть его назад ? Если опять попаду в активити .

Comment: об этом я не подумал, лучше наверное сделать как сказано по ссылке, которую скинул ЮрийСПБ :D